# On the uniform boundedness principle and the space of functions of bounded variation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

Let $U$ be a bounded smooth domain of $\mathbb{R}^d$. We write $m$ for the Lebesgue measure on $U$. A function $f \in L^1(U,m)$ has bounded variation in $U$ if
\begin{align*}
V(f,U):=\sup \left\{\int_{U}f\,\text{div}\varphi\,dm : \varphi \in C^1_{c}(U;\mathbb{R}^d),\, \sup_{x \in U}|\varphi(x)| \le 1. \right\}<\infty.
\end{align*}
Here, $|\varphi(x)|=\{\varphi_1(x)^2+\cdots+\varphi_d(x)^2\}^{1/2}$. We denote by $BV(U)$ the set of functions of bounded variation in $U$. For $f \in BV(U)$, we set
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{BV(U)}=\|f\|_{L^1(U,m)}+V(f,U),
\end{align*}
where $\|f\|_{L^1(U,m)}$ is the $L^1$-norm of $f$.

The following theorem is well-known (now $U$ is a bounded smooth domain):

> Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a bounded sequence in $BV(U)$. Then, there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ and $f \in L^1(U,m)$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty}f_{n_k}=f$ in $L^1(U,m)$.

**My question**

Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a (not necessarily bounded) sequence in $BV(U)$. We assume that $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a bounded  sequeene in $L^1(U,m)$, and for any $\varphi \in C_{c}^1(U;\mathbb{R}^d)$,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{U}f_n\,\text{div}\varphi\,dm=\int_{U}f\,\text{div}\varphi\,dm\quad {\rm (A)}
\end{align*}
for some $f \in BV(U)$. Of course, this does not imply that $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a bounded sequence in $BV(U)$ (the condition (A) is not sufficient to use the uniform  boundedeness principle). However, $C_{c}^\infty(U;\mathbb{R}^d)$ (with the topology induced  by the  seminorms) is a complete metric space. Then, the condition (A) and the uniform boundedness principle should show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n =f$ in a strong sense.

**What does this convergence mean? If the convergence  is  metrizable, please tell me the metric.**

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. But as a note, among sufficiently smooth functions of compact support, $\operatorname{div} \phi = \psi$ has a solution $\phi$ precisely if $\int \psi \,dm = 0$. In other words (A) characterizes weak convergence modulo averages. Thus denoting $C_f := \int f dm$, we have that (A) is true if and only if $(f_n-C_{f_n}) \,dm \to (f - C_f)\, dm$ in the sense of measures. Also note that if (A) holds for some $f$, then it also holds for any $f+a$, $a \in \mathbb{R}$ without changing the $f_n$.